# Cannot retrieve Date from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Function that retrieves some data from Firestore. I'm able to show back to the client all the information except for the Dates which return back to the client as an empty object.

**Firebase Function:**

```
exports.getPosts = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  .....
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection("posts").get();
    var posts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
      id: doc.id,
      author: doc.data().author,
      message: doc.data().message,
      lastChangeDate: doc.data().lastChangeDate.toDate(),
    }));
    console.log(posts);
    return posts;
.....
```

I also used **toDate()** to convert lastChangeDate from Timestamp to a Javascript Object Date.
The **console.log** shows:

```
{
      id: 'doc id',
      author: 'Bill',
      message: 'blah blah',
      lastChangeDate: 2021-04-24T08:03:01.024Z
}
```

**Client side:**

Then in my client I've tryed to retrieve the data after calling the firebase function, but I've got an empty object only for lastChangeDate.

```
const snapshot = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("getPosts");
var doc = await snapshot();
var array = doc.data.map(item => ({
          id: item.id,
          author: item.author,
          message: item.message,
          lastChangeDate: item.lastChangeDate,
}));
console.log(array);
```

The **console.log** shows:

```
{id: "xxxxxxxxxx", author: "Bill", message: "blah blah", lastChangeDate: {…}}
author: "Bill"
id: "xxxxxxxxxx"
lastChangeDate: Object
__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Object**
message: "blah blah"
....
```

As you can see, the lastChangeDate returns back to the client as an empty Object and I'm not able to show correctly the Date and parse it to any format.

What is wrong in my code? Please, help

Comment: Is the field `lastChangeDate` is of type Timestamp?

Comment: yes, firebase returns a Timestamp in doc.data().lastChangeDate. However, using toDate() I obtained a JS Date object.  This object goes to the client as null

Answer (score 1):

Your `lastChangeDate` in Firebase Function cannot be JSON encoded so you should do it your self by changing `lastChangeDate: doc.data().lastChangeDate.toDate(),` to  `lastChangeDate: doc.data().lastChangeDate.toDate().toJSON()` and parsing that date string on client.